# Cant click the infowindow android google map v2

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget, android-webview

I have a problem in clicking the window tap.

My code is as follows:

```
public class GamapA extends FragmentActivity implements OnInfoWindowClickListener{


Marker myMarkerOne;

Gmap gm;

  gm = ((SupportMapFragment)(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))).getMap();
             gm.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);


 gm.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);

LatLng one = new LatLng(12.786608, 80.221916);

   myMarkerOne = gm.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(one)
            .title("Test")
            .snippet("Testing")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));       

@Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(final Marker marker) 
{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(marker.getPosition().equals(myMarkerOne))
        {

    Toast.makeText(GamapChF.this, "Hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    .show();
        }
    }
```

I didn't get toast message when the window been clicked.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

its not give you toast because

marker.getPosition() give you like `lat/lng: (23.06831002668264,72.58109997957945)` (for check this print log like `Log.e("marker.getPosition()-->", "" + marker.getPosition());`)

and you are passing like: `new LatLng(23.06831, 72.58110);`

as you see both `(23.06831002668264,72.58109997957945)` and `(23.06831, 72.58110)` are not equals. so **it never give you `Toast`**.

So, Insted of that i ll sagest you use Title for comparing or massage like:

```
if (marker.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("Start")) {
            Toast.makeText(showMaps.this, "You have click on start -->",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("marker.getPosition()-->", "" + marker.getPosition());
        }
```